# YouTube Data API - Get Channel ID from Email

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve Youtube channel ID and name using Youtube data API but I'm getting empty item. I have only the Youtube user email account. Is there away to get the channel details from the email only?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the user channel ID from user email.
I have tried to use `forUsername` parameter but this works only for some users (legacy issue).
The only I have found is to use Google Signin for iOS implementation which allow you yo signin with your google account. In order to have that ability to get YouTube data it require additional scope configuration as follows:

```
let scope: NSString = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
let currentScopes: NSArray = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = currentScopes.arrayByAddingObject(scope)
```

Now, you can run the following YouTube data API with Access Token:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token={oauth_token}
```

The access token, you will get from `user.authentication.accessToken`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of retrieving YouTube channels via their associated e-mailaddress at this moment.

Comment: So I need to know from advance the user channelID or username (forusername)?

Comment: @NoamMaoz Exactly. However, if you let the user authenticate through OAuth, you can specify the `mine` parameter. Also note that the `forUsername` parameter only accepts the legacy usernames (the /user/username ones).

Comment: Do you an example of how to use user authenticate through OAuth with mine parameter in Swift? https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: @NoamMaoz Check out this documentation article: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps

Comment: Thanks, I have started to check and implement the Google Sign-In for iOS (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) and I'm able to login to my account but I'm still check how to get the channel ID after I have the user profile and token.