# Get User YouTube Playlists with email or username using the YouTube API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I am using the newest YouTube API (v3 I believe). This is the documentation I have been going from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/.

I am able to get a users YouTube playlists with the channel ID by making this call in javascript:

```
function getPlaylists(channelId) {
    return $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", { part: 'snippet', channelId: channelId, key: key });
}
```

When I have the playlists I am able to get the PlaylistID property of each playlist. Using the PlaylistID I can get all the videos for the playlist using the javascript code:

```
function getPlaylistVideos(playlistId) {
    return $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems', { part: 'snippet', playlistId: playlistId, key: key });
}
```

I really don't like that I have to make a user try and find their ChannelId to pull in their playlists. I want to be able to have the user just pass their email or username to do this. Is this possible? Is it possible without using the YouTube Authentication? If not, is there any good sources on the usage of the YouTube Authenication Service?

Comment: Have a look at `forUserName` here... https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters

Comment: @Archer I have a feeling I am going blind. I will give that a shot....I am sure it will work. I will let you know

Comment: Well I just tried that and it doesn't work. I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451543/youtube-data-api-get-channel-id-from-email and it looks like it is not possible at this time without using the OAuth.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.  I had issues using the YT API as well, finding it frustrating to not be able to do seemingly simple tasks.  I ended up embedding playlist IDs into links to get round my issues, but that obviously isn't an answer here.  I hope you get it sorted - good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in three steps for the username, of course the email require Oauth2 so it's not possible.

**Step 1**

With the YouTube API v3 with the resource `channel.list`

Use this parameters to get the channel ID of a channel with the username:

```
part: 'snippet'
forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
```

And you get :

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/lVXRA_GH5DhBajCt1cOeuB4TWbw\"",
   "id": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
```

Now you get the ID of the channel `UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw`

**Step 2**

With the YouTube API v3 with the resource `playlist.list`

Use this parameters to get all the playlist ID of a channel :

```
part: 'snippet'
channelId: 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw'
```

And you get all playlist id

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/sxN5XCGvIn_Rnsan74s_A_k16L8\"",
   "id": "PLOU2XLYxmsIKXYR_3iOWnI4h1Do_aa8dn",
```

Now **Step 3**

With the YouTube API v3 with the resource `playlist.list`

Use this parameters to get the videos into playlistID of a channel :

```
part: 'snippet'
playlistId: 'PLOU2XLYxmsIKXYR_3iOWnI4h1Do_aa8dn'
```

And you get all playlist id

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/WFwMbOGG8nLHKF8tH1W41WNFJBk\"",
   "id": "UExPVTJYTFl4bXNJS1hZUl8zaU9Xbkk0aDFEb19hYThkbi41NkI0NEY2RDEwNTU3Q0M2",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-04-18T17:33:55.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "#Love4Dev - What Magnus Hyttsten loves most about the power of mobile APIs",
```

And you get all video in that playlist;

The important part is step one, user only need to enter the username of their channel, like in my example : https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers